# android admob resize on landscape

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have declared adMob on manifest like

```
<activity 
           android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
          />
```

It is resized properly when device rotacion but now I must add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to activity that contains adMob in order to prevent activity reloading. I am reaching it but now adMob is not scaled when landscape. onConfigChanges event I could now force adMob to be resized with proper landscape dimensions. How? thank you.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929963/admob-ad-not-resizing-correctly-upon-screen-orientation-includes-pictures and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703152/smart-banner-container-view-wont-resize

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the same problem, but found a work-around.

My AdView sits at the bottom of the page, inside of a Relative layout.  It looks correct when loaded, so I assumed the `LayoutParams` were correct.  To fix this issue, I had to remove everything from the `RelativeLayout`, create a new AdView, and add it all back in the correct order, with the original `LayoutParams`.

Something like:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    View contentFrame = findViewById(R.id.contentFrameLayout);

    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) adView.getParent();
    LayoutParams mapFrameParams = contentFrame.getLayoutParams();
    LayoutParams adViewParams = adView.getLayoutParams();

    parent.removeView(adView);
    parent.removeView(contentFrame);

    AdView newAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, getString(R.string.admob_pubId));

    newAdView.setId(R.id.adView);

    parent.addView(newAdView, adViewParams);
    parent.addView(contentFrame,mapFrameParams);
    newAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
```

This works for me, but still feels like a hack.

Comment: My application require support of api level 4 so onConfigurationChanged is not supported. Is there no other way to manage this ?

Comment: Just in case someone need the solution for api level < 8, you just have to add @TargetApi(8) before @Override.

Comment: Removing and adding "contectFrame" is redundant.

Comment: Calling adView.destroy() before creating the new adView will free up valuable resources.

Comment: @user1951805 It is redundant, but at the time of this answer, it was relevant.  I have not revisited this issue since this post, so I do not know if this workaround is even still needed.

Comment: Justin Smith, this workaround is still needed. I am using it minus removing and adding contentFrame.

Comment: Updated AdView creation to the current AdMob's SDK in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29516024/1816603

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that doesn't work anymore when using latest library com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0. Orientation seems to be cache within the library and will reflect actual orientation after a few minutes

Answer (score 4):

Not enough Rep to reply directly but you are correct Justin Smith. As Eric Leichtenschlag states here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/8Ch7VmAm7RE/34Tdw6Zz4jAJ the AdView needs to be recreated if you are using SMART_BANNER

What I did was remove the adView from the layout, destroy the adview, recreate it, add it back into the layout and then issued a AdRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the source, I don't think I had seen that yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this setup:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/adkey"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

The `SMART_BANNER` automatically selects the best size and type for your ad.

In your `onConfigurationChanged` method you would just request a new ad for the `AdView`.

Note that you might need to add `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`.

Comment: banner is properly requested again when device rotation using your suggestion but remains at same size

Comment: I've the same issue, banner is properly requested again when device rotation using your suggestion but remains at same size, Have you fixed this?

Comment: I think that the adView calculates it's size when it is added to the layout, not when it receives the ad (this would be nice, however), so I think that must be why this is not working.