# Admob Interstitial orientation is locked to the initial device orientation on startup

Tags: android, admob

I'm having a problem integrating Admob interstitial ads. My app supports both portrait AND landscape orientation, and as such I have set the manifest to:

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

The problem is that the Admob interstitial appears to be fixed/locked to the original orientation of the device on start up.  E.g. if I start the app in portrait orientation, and then rotate the device to landscape, then show an ad, then it appears on its side (in portrait orientation)...

How can I force the interstitial to reset to the new device orientation?

I am loading the ad like this:

```
interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(activity);
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(Config.ADMOB_UNIT_ID);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    .build();

interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and then showing it like this:

```
interstitialAd.show();
```

Comment: Are you requesting the ad at startup, then changing the orientation before showing it? If so, that would definitely produce the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @RedBrogdon Yes, however all subsequent ads are also in the wrong orientation. I.e. After I show an ad, I request another one, and that second one is also incorrect, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this. In the end it came down to re-requesting the ad on orientation change, and importantly, running that request in the UI thread.

Comment: yes, we have to update any type of ad when orientation changes: Interstitial, Banner

Comment: Did you just call method .load when orientation changes or you create new instance of `InterstitialAd` as well? `InterstitialAd(this)`

Comment: Yes. We have to create new instance as well when orientation changes, because calling `loadAd` won't work if ad is already loaded

Answer (score 0):

Dont know whether this link will be helpful or not...
If my answer is irrelevant dnt downvote...Her is the link
[android admob resize on landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281562/android-admob-resize-on-landscape)

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for [SMART_BANNER](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/banner)??

Use it as:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="XXXXX">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: No, I'm using a full screen interstitial ad.

Comment: Can't read the question carefully? Interstitial type of ad, not a banner

Comment: Who gave this question a bounty lol