# AdMob Interstitial Landscape-only Orientation

Tags: java, android, admob, screen-orientation, interstitial

I have an [Android, Java] game which runs in landscape orientation and shows AdMob interstitial ads.

I noticed that the ads we displaying in the orientation in which the device was *when the app was launched*.  For example when using a tablet if the device was held in portrait mode when the app was initially launched but then rotated to landscape (so that the app could be used as it's forced into landscape), the ads would still show in portrait orientation.

I should point out that my app uses the following in the manifest...

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:screenOrientation="locked"...
```

The reason for this is that I have a splash theme which I want to show *immediately* upon launch.  If I lock the app here to landscape (android:screenOrientation="landscape"), there is a noticeable pause before the app actually launches if the device's orientation is portrait... ie, it needs to rotate to landscape.  I found this solution elsewhere on SO.

In *onCreate*, I use the following to change the orientation...

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

So, everything works as expected... launch, splash shown immediately, apps' orientation changes and loads.

I did some research and learned that I should implement onConfigurationChanged and load a new ad when the rotation had changed, which is what I did...

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        loadInterstitial(); // This is a just my own method which calls the static .load() method and carries a few additional tasks
    }
}
```

With this in place, all ads apart from the initial one are indeed shown in landscape mode.  This makes sense as I'm loading a new ad when the old one is dismissed.  So if for some reason the current ad is shown in portrait and is dismissed, a new one is requested.  The app then rotates back to its correct orientation (landscape), which triggers the onConfigurationChanged callback which requests a new ad (now a landscape ad as long as the device is now physically in a landscape orientation).

However, what I can't understand is why my initial ad is *still* loaded in portrait mode.  Here is what I think should happen and what actually does happen...

- Tablet held in portrait mode
- App lauched
- Splashscreen shown in portrait mode
- onCreate requests landscape orientation
- Ad is loaded (app still in portrait so portrait ad loaded)
- App (still showing splashscreen), rotates to correct orientation (landscape)... device is rotated to match (now held in landscape so app can be used)
- onConfigurationChanged triggers and re-loads ad (should now load landscape ad, but doesn't seem to)
- Ad loaded above shows (in portrait mode)

It's extremely frustrating.  If I remove 'lock' from my manifest then the ads are OK (even the initial one)...  **(See edit)**, but then I have the horrible dead-time on app cold start when a rotation is required.

It seems that even though the orientation has changed, AdMob still uses the 'locked' orientation from the manifest and still think it's in portrait mode.

I've looked all over but can't find a solution.

Help appreciated.  Any code in Java please not Kotlin.

**Edit**

Above I wrote:

> If I remove 'lock' from my manifest then the ads are OK (even the initial one).

This is incorrect.  I meant to say that "if I change 'locked' to 'landscape'" rather than simply "If I remove 'lock'"

Comment: I think its by design that loaded ad will follow orientation initially specified. Reloading ad on orientation change is the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566953/admob-interstitial-orientation-is-locked-to-the-initial-device-orientation-on-st

Comment: also i recommend to post it on google moblesdk group. They will definitely confirm this or provide fix in future release https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk

Comment: Hi @AmodGokhale, thanks for the comment.  As stated in my question, I *am* re-loading the ad on orientation change, and this does work... just not for the initial ad.  (I've confirmed that a new ad is loaded *after* the orientation has changed to landscape, but it's still a portrait ad for some reason).  Cheers

Comment: @Zippy did you find the solution. Please help if you have.