# Android AdView orientation change height is 0

Tags: android, admob, android-view, android-orientation

I'm trying to reload manually an AdView when orientation changes. I'm able to issue the request and get an add back. The problem is that when I try to remove the old view and add a new one, I get this warning:

```
W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 592x32 dp, but only has 640x0 dp.
```

And the view is not shown. This is my `onConfigurationChanged` method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams adViewParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    adViewParent.removeView(adView);
    adView.destroy();

    AdView newAdView = new AdView(this);
    newAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    newAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_ad_unit_id_main));
    newAdView.setLayoutParams(adViewParams);
    newAdView.setId(R.id.adView);

    adView = newAdView;
    adViewParent.addView(adView);

    loadAd();
}
```

I've read other similar answers like this one [android admob resize on landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281562/android-admob-resize-on-landscape) but they didn't work for me and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams adViewParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Utils.dpToPx(32));
```

And hide `adViewParent.setVisibility(GONE)` if loading of ad is failed

Comment: Thank you for the comment. With this the warning is gone but the view is still not shown. Also, I'd rather not hard-code values and rely instead on the WRAP_CONTENT attribute